# How to prevent rounding off of the last digit when using string formatting in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, rounding, string-formatting

The following code:

```
>>> a
54685.1546432
>>> c = f"{a:,f}"
>>> c
```

Gives the following output:

```
'54,685.154643'
```

As you can see, python has automatically rounded off the last digit from 'a' to 'c'.
Desirable answer for 'c' is

```
'54,685.1546432'
```

Can anyone suggest how to achieve this?

Edit: After some research, I found out this can be achieved by the following: f"{a:,}"
Thanks, everyone for the answers, if someone can direct me how to close this question it would be great!

Comment: P.S. After some research I found out this can be achieved by the following: f"{a:,}"

Comment: You don't "close" the question, you select an answer.  If there's an answer below that works for you then select it, and people will see that this question has been answered.

If you don't see a satisfactory answer, you can simply answer it yourself and then select that as the answer.  I suggest looking at David Barcene's answer first, since it looks like it might be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to add the comma separator for the thousands then you should do:

```
c = f"{a:,}"
```

Adding an f after the comma is not needed unless you want to specify decimal precision, in which case you would do:

```
c = f"{a:,.7f}"
```

Where .7f specifies 7 decimal places after the period.